# parrallel charging of loads

Tags: parallel, solar-energy

I have the following setup;
20v solar panel -->> MPPT chagre controller (sparkfun sunny buddy) -->> battery(3.7v 7000mAh & 5v microcontroller in parallel, see diagram below.

In full sunlight and approx. 19v input to the charge controller from the solar panel;

1. Should there be power applied to both the battery and the microcontroller?
2. If the battery is low ( i.e. charging ) will the microcontroller still get power?

Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcMOou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper charge controller for the battery, and a suitable voltage regulator (probably DC-DC converter) to provide power to the Pi.

Both devices must be designed to operate from the voltage provided by the MPPT controller.

Comment: The MPPT controller IS a DC-DC convertor and charge controller.

Comment: I have a voltage regulator at the Raspberry Pi

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how voltage from the controller is divided between the battery, when it's charging, and the load ( microcontroller ), does the load get its power from the battery along or can it get it from the controller when available?